# PAM LDAP: why does passwd command ask for "(current) LDAP Password: "?

Tags: ubuntu, pam, ldap

I have an openLDAP service on a Debian 11 server, and I have set up PAM on a Ubuntu 22.04 PC; I am beginning to be very confused. I can log in withouot a problem, but when I want to change password, I see some odd behaviours. At first, I could change the password, but I first had to enter the `LDAP Password` and then got asked twice for the new password + re-entering it.

Now, however, after having messed around with `/etc/pam.d/common-password` a bit, it looks like this:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be
# used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

# Explanation of pam_unix options:
# The "yescrypt" option enables
#hashed passwords using the yescrypt algorithm, introduced in Debian
#11.  Without this option, the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases
#used the option "sha512"; if a shadow password hash will be shared
#between Debian 11 and older releases replace "yescrypt" with "sha512"
#for compatibility .  The "obscure" option replaces the old
#`OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in login.defs.  See the pam_unix manpage
#for other options.

# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
#password requisite     pam_pwquality.so retry=3
#password [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass yescrypt
password  [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure try_first_pass yescrypt debug
#password sufficient      pam_sss.so use_authtok
password  [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_authtok debug
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password  requisite     pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password  required      pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
password  optional  pam_gnome_keyring.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

and I see this when trying to change password:

```
(base) jan@enki:~$ passwd
(current) LDAP Password: 
passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

This is in `/var/log/auth.log` (the empty lines in the output are because I hit enter a couple of times after I started `passwd` in another terminal):

```
(base) root@enki:/var/log# tail -f auth.log
...
Jan 27 16:12:59 enki passwd[392340]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): username [jan] obtained
Jan 27 16:12:59 enki passwd[392340]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "jan" does not exist in /etc/passwd
Jan 27 16:12:59 enki passwd[392340]: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): nslcd request config (1)
Jan 27 16:12:59 enki passwd[392340]: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): nslcd account check; user=jan


Jan 27 16:13:05 enki passwd[392340]: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): nslcd authentication; user=jan
Jan 27 16:13:05 enki passwd[392340]: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): authentication succeeded
Jan 27 16:13:05 enki passwd[392340]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): username [jan] obtained
Jan 27 16:13:05 enki passwd[392340]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): user "jan" does not exist in /etc/passwd
Jan 27 16:13:05 enki passwd[392340]: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): nslcd request config (1)
Jan 27 16:13:05 enki passwd[392340]: pam_ldap(passwd:chauthtok): nslcd account check; user=jan
...
```

To me it looks like `pam_ldap` authenticates successfully, so why does it fail? And secondarily, why am I asked for the new password twice?

Comment: This might be a silly question, but if it was working until you messed around with the config, and you want it to be working, what's stopping you putting the config back how it started?  What were you trying to achieve by changing the config?  It needs the current LDAP password to authenticate with the LDAP server for the password change.  Prompting twice for your new password is a pretty standard activity to try to ensure the password is set to what you think it's set to.

Comment: @bxm What I mean 'asking twice' was that I type in the new password, and repeat it; and then I have to do it again - in total four times. The reason I started changing the config was that I 1) don't want to have to type in the LDAP password (on another client I don't have to, but that is Debian, not Ubuntu; and there may be reasons, which I don't yet know, for Ubuntu to be different). And 2) I don't want to type in the new password 4 times.